# Integrate iTunes Movie and Video rental into our iPhone app

Tags: iphone, itunes-store, movies

Is it possible to implement iTunes Movie Rentals and purchases in our own app ?

If yes any resource will be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've already figured this out or not but the api is here:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

You can get the original movie price. If you find out how to integrate or get the rental info definitely send it my way!